# javascript regular expression to extract middle part

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like this: `"http://www.example.com/hello/world/ab/c/d.html"` (or this: `"http://www.example.com/hello/world/ab/d.html"`)

I want to extract the content between `http://www.example.com/hello/world/` and `d.html`. What should the generic regular expression be?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'middle'. In this case, you are asking for the 3rd and 4th path components -- hardly a 'generic' definition of middle.

Comment: just the components between 'http:/ /xxx/xxx/xxx' and 'xxx.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
/^http:\/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/(.*)\/[^\/]*$/
```

This (complicated-looking) expression skips the domain and the first two path components, then extracts all the bits before the final path component.

Example:

```
>>> 'http://www.google.com/hello/world/ab/c/d.html'.match(/^http:\/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/(.*)\/[^\/]*$/)
["http://www.google.com/hello/world/ab/c/d.html", "ab/c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are looking for is this: /^http\://www.google.com/hello/world/(.*/)d.htm$/

http://jsfiddle.net/rDvJK/

```
function getIt(fromWhat) {
    var matches = fromWhat.match(/^http\:\/\/www\.google\.com\/hello\/world\/(.*\/)d.htm$/);
    console.log(matches);
    return matches[1];
}
getIt("http://www.google.com/hello/world/ab/c/d.htm");
```